# Efficiently get all items of a vector with a given id

Tags: rust

Say I have a vector of items where each item has an id, like in the example below. I can of course get all the items in the vector with a given id using something like `large_vector.iter().filter(|item| item.id == given_id)`. However, for improved performance I can do some preprocessing and sort the vector by item id and store the bounds for each id, like in the example below. This way I can quickly access a slice of the vector for any given id. I end up doing this alot but feel like I am reinventing the wheel and needlessly opening myself up to bugs. Is there a better way to do this directly, preferably using the standard library else some other library?

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, ops::Range};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    id: String,
    val: f64,
}
impl Item {
    fn new(id: &str, val: f64) -> Item {
        Item { id: id.into(), val }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut large_vector = vec![
        Item::new("C", 2.21),
        Item::new("A", 34.2),
        Item::new("B", 23.54),
        Item::new("C", 34.34),
        Item::new("C", 45.21),
        Item::new("B", 21.34),
    ];

    // first sort by id
    large_vector.sort_by(|item1, item2| item1.id.cmp(&item2.id));
    dbg!(&large_vector);

    // now create a HasMap storing bounds for each id
    let mut lookup = HashMap::new();
    let mut start: usize = 0;
    let mut end: usize = 0;
    if let Some(first_item) = large_vector.get(0) {
        let mut current_id = first_item.id.clone();
        // insert bound if entered new id section or is last item
        for item in &large_vector {
            if current_id != item.id {
                lookup.insert(current_id.clone(), Range { start, end });
                current_id = item.id.clone();
                start = end;
            }
            end += 1;
        }
        lookup.insert(current_id.clone(), Range { start, end });
    }

    // test by getting the items for a given id
    dbg!(&lookup);
    let range = lookup.get("C").unwrap();
    dbg!(range);
    let items = large_vector[range.start..range.end]
        .iter()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    dbg!(items);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:26] &large_vector = [
    Item {
        id: "A",
        val: 34.2,
    },
    Item {
        id: "B",
        val: 23.54,
    },
    Item {
        id: "B",
        val: 21.34,
    },
    Item {
        id: "C",
        val: 2.21,
    },
    Item {
        id: "C",
        val: 34.34,
    },
    Item {
        id: "C",
        val: 45.21,
    },
]
[src/main.rs:47] &lookup = {
    "A": 0..1,
    "B": 1..3,
    "C": 3..6,
}
[src/main.rs:49] range = 3..6
[src/main.rs:53] items = [
    Item {
        id: "C",
        val: 2.21,
    },
    Item {
        id: "C",
        val: 34.34,
    },
    Item {
        id: "C",
        val: 45.21,
    },
]
```

Comment: If you can change the vector, why aren't you using HashSet instead? It takes O(n) space and O(1) to fetch an item with ID.

Comment: @Mr.R duplicates? Although that could be solved by nested vector

Comment: @Mr.R I don't understand how a set would be useful here, could you explain more?

Comment: First, as @Finomnis mentioned, does your list contain unique items?

Comment: @Mr.R No, all the times I've used this technique recently the items have had a unique id field. Though conceivably there could be other times where I have vectors containing duplicates, but I could probably just add a unique id in those cases.

Comment: @Mr.R Not unique items, unique identifiers.  And no, his example contains duplicate identifiers.

Comment: @Max888 Ok now you completely lost me. You specifically ask for a "vector of items with a given ID"  and then you say "IDs are unique" - how does that make sense? Why would you need a vector if there can be only one of them? Why don't you just store all the items in a `HashSet` then? On the other hand, in your example you have  three items with the ID `"C"` - why do you say you have unique IDs then?

Comment: If you have unique IDs, use `HashSet<Item>` to store them instead of storing them in a vector. If you have duplicates, you could use `HashMap<String, Vec<Item>>`. But again, the question of whether or not keys are unique is extremely important in your question, so I'm really confused why in your example they aren't and then in the comment you say they are.

Comment: @Finomnis Yes sorry, there are definitely duplicate ids/identifiers. Mr. R said "does your list contain unique items" which it does - each item is unique in it's combination of id and value. Plus in the real world each item also has a unique id field, but I excluded that here as I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: @Finomnis thanks for the suggestion of just storing the data in a HashMap in the first place. This might be possible in some cases, but usually I need to keep the data in a vector, I'm just able to sort it.

Comment: @Finomnis Just rereading all this as I missed some of your comments. Sorry it turned in to such a mess, Mr. R start the confusion with asking about items not identifiers, and I continued the confusion by talking about "unique id field" without making it clear that this would be an *additional*, *unique* id field to what is in the example. The field in the example would probably be better named `reference_id` or something.

Comment: I think this question should be in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, then. I'll answer it anyway because it's fine :) but in future this will probably be your target audience

Comment: Converting your vector into `HashSet::<String, Vec<Item>>`  gives you O(1) for finding items by IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your items **have** to be in a vector, and you can only sort them, I can think of two possibilities:

- The solution you proposed. It should be the fastest one for lookup, but has the drawback that the lookup tables get completely invalidated every time you insert/remove an item.
- Keep the vector sorted and perform a `log(n)` based divide-and-conquer search to get the range. If you are interested in what I mean with that, I can provide you with some code.

But in general, I think a vector is simply the wrong data structure. I'd try to change that first.